# How to implement paypal using Web Api on Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, paypal, webapi

I am developing a mobile app using Magento2 Web Api. I am wondering how to implement Paypal for my mobile app. What versions of Paypal (express, etc.), is it used as an offline payment method?, do I need to configure something in Paypal's website, in Magento2?